# Effect of dielectric on electric field outside the dielectric

Tags: electrostatics, dielectric

I have the problem given in Irodov stated as follows

- Two positive charges $q_1$ and $q_2$ are placed a distance $r$ apart in air, now a dielectric slab of thickness $t$ $(t\lt r)$ with relative permittivity $k$. Find the force of electrostatic interaction between the two charges.

My question is what effect does the dielectric have on the field outside the dielectric medium.

The answer which I had been directed to just states the dielectric behaves as though it's thickness was t√k, but there is no mathematical proof for that. Hence, I request for a proper mathematical proof for the effect.

Comment: @GuruVishnu I understood the special case where the dielectric fills the entire region, but I don't understand the generalisation made to arrive at the mathematical manipulation

Comment: The only answer to the linked question says that the effect of dielectric is independent of the region filled. The dielectric creates some kind of path difference which is somewhat similar to what optical media (other than vacuum) does to light waves. I agree that it is not supported by any valid reasons or good resources. However, the question (v1) you've asked seems to be an exact duplicate of the linked. I'd recommend you to either edit your question reflecting the difference and doubts regarding that answer or start a bounty to the linked one.

Comment: @GuruVishnu I understand that the effect is related but I am not able to accept it without a mathematical proof, (which is possible in case of optics)

Comment: @GuruVishnu I asked my teacher, he said the method is absolutely incorrect

Comment: Fine. Can you edit your question stating the reason why that method is incorrect? As I said earlier, you can either edit this one or start a bounty for that question. If your edit clearly differentiates this question from that one by stating your expectations of a better answer, I'll vote to reopen your question.